# Snowflake Stream status monitoring

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have many streams becoming stale. How do I monitor the stream status? beside the "desc stream" and "show stream" command, is there any information view that I can query the stream information and status so that I can proactively monitor the stream stat

checked the snowflake.account_usage views but do not see any view that I can query for the streams info or status

Comment: What additional information, that SHOW STREAMS doesn’t provide, are you looking for?